# IllegalArgumentException: Cannot deserialize instance of

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I have a spring boot application where I have a BlogsService calling a Blogs Repository and it should return a list of blogs matching the search query passed. I get the following which is caused by line 76. Any ideas? Thanks

Line 76:

```
return objectMapper.convertValue(searchEntity, BlogDetailsResponse.class);
```

***IllegalArgumentException: Cannot deserialize instance of `package.dto.BlogDetailsResponse` out of START_ARRAY token
at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]
at com.cor.devsquareawsservice.services.impl.BlogServiceImpl.searchBlogs(BlogServiceImpl.java:76) ~[classes/:na]***

BlogServiceImpl.java

```
  @Override
  public BlogDetailsResponse searchBlogs(SearchBlogsRequest searchBlogsRequest) {
    try {
      final List<BlogEntity> searchEntity = blogsRepository.searchBlogs(searchBlogsRequest.getSearchBlogsQuery());
      return objectMapper.convertValue(searchEntity, BlogDetailsResponse.class);
    } catch (final Exception exception) {
      log.error(exception);
      throw new DevSquareDynamoDBException(ExceptionConstants.SERVICE_CREATE_BLOG_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE, exception);
    }
  }
```

BlogsRepository.java

```
  public List<BlogEntity> searchBlogs(String query) {
    try {
      DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();
      scanExpression.addFilterCondition("title", new Condition()
              .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.CONTAINS)
              .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(query)));
      return dynamoDBMapper.scan(BlogEntity.class, scanExpression);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      log.error("failed to get blogs > " + query);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: searchEntity is a list of BlogEntity. BlogDetailsResponse is not a list, is an object.  Please, give more details about BlogDetailsResponse code and BlogEntity.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue. I needed to map ever the list and covert each entity.

```
  public List<BlogDetailsResponse> searchBlogs(SearchBlogsRequest searchBlogsRequest) {
    try {
      return blogsRepository.searchBlogs(searchBlogsRequest.getSearchBlogsQuery()).stream().map(e -> objectMapper
              .convertValue(e, BlogDetailsResponse.class))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (final Exception exception) {
      log.error(exception);
      throw new DevSquareDynamoDBException(ExceptionConstants.SERVICE_SEARCH_BLOGS_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE, exception);
    }
  }
```